# strict_types declaration must be the very first statement in magento 2.3.1

Tags: magento2, xml, setup-di-compile

I have Magento 2.3.1. I am facing below error when I run command `setup:di:compile`.

> Fatal error:  strict_types declaration must be the very first
>   statement in the script in
>   vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/ChangeQuoteControl.php on line 8

Answer (score 1):

> src/Framework/Error/Deprecated.php

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);
<?php
/*
 * This file is part of PHPUnit.
 *
```

> src/Framework/Error/Error.php

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);
<?php
/*
 * This file is part of PHPUnit.
 *
```

> src/Framework/Error/Notice.php

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);
<?php
/*
 * This file is part of PHPUnit.
 *
```

> src/Framework/Error/Warning.php

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);
<?php
/*
 * This file is part of PHPUnit.
 *
```

For more details refer:
https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/2791

https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/commit/70ccf0370f0b99c22819d3730167a7d448911b9e